# How do Idle games progress while not active?

Tags: unity, android, realtime

A hallmark of many idle games is the ability to still progress (or at least regain resources) while the game isn't active. The device can even be off.

Initially I figured they just calculated progress off system time next time it was started, but they do not appear fooled by messing with the clock.

How do they manage this specific feat?

Comment: Unfortunately, how do other games work is not on-topic here. You might reword the question to highlight a specific problem you're having while developing your own game, with the steps you've taken to solve it.

Comment: @Vaillancourt Trying to replicate a game feature is off-topic? Okay.

Comment: The question is not formulated as such. You might want to reword it and highlight what you have tried so far but did not work for your specific situation.

Comment: @Vaillancourt At this point it hardly matters, I've gotten the information I needed :)

Comment: Sure :) You still may consider accepting one of those if it makes sense to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do actually use the clock the way you think they do, but they'll sometimes make network requests to get the time from a more reliable source. Try disabling the internet, closing the game and then setting the clock. They should either completely refuse to load or have the wrong values.

Answer (score 2):

They **do** mess with some time and calculate everything from it. The question is which time do they use?

Some games *do* use system time, and on their case, if you change your time locally, you can fool them to earn rewards.

Other games use server time, so when the game starts, it attempts to connect to a server to get that time and make all the calculations. This is more likely the case with web games, as you can't access them as easily as other games.